# MCMC Bayesian approach - centering and standardizing

Tags: regression, bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo

Why is centering and standardizing generally recommended
in the Bayesian approach (MCMCregress) ?

Does it apply equally for non-informative as well as informative priors?

**EDIT:**
We have been working on a specific example. The following screen shots provide the summary from the R output. Does the centering and standardizing improve the prediction? How will the parameters be interpreted once they have been centered and standardized?

```
mcmc.logmod <- MCMCregress(log(Salary) ~ AtBat + Hits + HmRun, data = red.hitters,
                           family = gaussian, burnin = 1000, mcmc = 10000, verbose = 0)
summary(mcmc.logmod)
plot(mcmc.logmod, col = "brown")
```

[image]

Centered and standardized:

```
mcmc.logmod2 <- MCMCregress(salary ~ atbat + hits + hmrun, data = sub.hitters, family = gaussian,
                            burnin = 1000, mcmc = 10000, verbose = 0)
summary(mcmc.logmod2)
```

[image]

Comment: Why should it be..?

Comment: Thats what we have been told in the lecture. I am trying to find out if that is his personal opinion or if there is a legit reason behind that statement?

Comment: It is hard to comment without knowing what the actual advice you were given was. However the general answer is no, there is no such recommendations.

Comment: @Tim I have added some context to my question. The actuall advice was literally "centering and standardizing generally recommended in the Bayesian approach"... I am trying to understand this, but i feel like i am missing something (possibly very basic)

Comment: Is it an advice or a question? Frow what you've pasted it seems that this is actually a question for you to answer...

Comment: @ Well I know that the confidence intervals are shorter after centering and standardizing, therefore more precission. Also the parameters become unitless, which doesn't matter here i guess, since the parameters are counts. But is that all? Is that enough to say that it is "generally recomended"? I think i am missing a point, therefore asking...

Comment: Well confidence intervals are shorter because scale of your variables has changed! If instead of transforming to unit variance you would transform your variables to have variance equal to 0.000000001 they would be even shorter but you wouldn't gain any additional precision thanks to such operation...

Comment: It is no more recommended than in the Frequentist approach.  There are times when you want to do it (to compare strengths of variables in different units).  There is no recommendation that "oh your're doing Bayesian you better standardize your variables then."

Comment: Would you include effective sample sizes from your 2 runs? I'm anticipating the difference in effective sampling rates will corroborate John Kruschke's answer nicely.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Mean centering or standardizing is done only to improve the efficiency of MCMC sampling (i.e., to reduce autocorrelation in the chains). In principle it is not necessary to mean center (or standardize), but then you'd have to wait around a lot longer for the chains to produce a reasonable effective sample size. (There is no guarantee that mean centering or standardizing will help in all applications, but it tends to help.)

The mean centering or standardizing does not change the parameter estimates. You do, however, have to transform back to the original scale.

Details of this are covered at length in [DBDA2E](https://sites.google.com/site/doingbayesiandataanalysis/). For linear regression, see Section 17.2.1.1 (p. 485+). For quadratic trend, Section 17.4 (p. 495). For multiple linear regression, Section 18.1.2 (p. 516). For logistic regression, Section 21.1.1 (pp. 624-625).